# Web application architecture question

Tags: .net, wcf, web-applications, architecture

We're planning to develop a medium - larger sized web appliaction

- mostly CRUD operations
- reporting
- intranet/internet ready

Someone had an idea to split the application into two separete solutions

1. ASP.NET Web application - frontend
2. Core application - data access,domain logic.. hosted in a windows service

The communication would be realized with WCF (tcp,named pipes)

I'm wondering what are the cons and pros of this solution ?

Mostly I'm worried about that the development proces will get to complex. All this communication over WCF.

Could you please share some thoughs or have you any experiences with a similar project ?

Comment: Please define medium/large. What is the expected traffic? Having layers separates logic and makes it easier to add e.g. caching as a new layer afterwards.

Comment: Lets start with 100 concurent users. But there is a potential of growing ...

Comment: you may have a look at this, similar topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527052/asp-net-web-application-architecture-design-advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to look at it, but if you code your application in a 'standard' n-tier fashion, so that the web front end is not relying on concrete classes from your back end, you 'could' put this in later on if needed, but doing it up front 'just in case' adds a lot of complexity to your system.

Another approach is the ability to put your application in a web farm with a load balancer - this reduces your code complexity and allows you scale out as required.

(I'd also note that 100 concurrent users isn't really all that large).

Comment: could you please be more specific on the web farm stuff ?

Comment: OK, for scaling, you code your n-tier application as normal, with the database on a separate server.  If load really increases, you put your site in a web farm, with many web application servers behind a load balancer - this allows you to easily scale your site, while still maintaining simple code.

Comment: I would note, that you need to consider sessions (InProc sessions are no good in this case) and cacheing etc in a different light in this case, but this is all doable.

Comment: this approach is only possible with the service separation (WCF) between layers ?

Comment: No, this approach is to avoid the need for service separation, as it adds complexity.  All your code runs on the same box, but you have multiple boxes.